# Alternative proof existence of nth root in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to understand this alternative proof to the well known Rudin problem:

> For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n=x$.

The proof is identical to how Rudin presents it until proving that $y^n=x$, where $y=\sup\{t\in\mathbb{R}|t>0,t^n<x\}$.

Now the proof, unlike Rudin, uses the following inequality
$$(1+\varepsilon)^n<1+3^n\varepsilon,\quad n\in\mathbb{N},$$
where $0<\varepsilon<1$. For the case $y^n<x$, we choose $\varepsilon<\frac{x-y^n}{3^ny^n}$ and
$$y^n(1+\varepsilon)^n<y^n(1+3^n\varepsilon)=y^n+3^ny^n\varepsilon<x\implies y(1+\varepsilon)\in\{t\in\mathbb{R}|t>0,t^n<x\},$$
which is a contradiction.

But, I do not understand the other case $y^n>x$, since the proof concludes that it is enough to take $\varepsilon<\frac{y^n-x}{1+3^n\varepsilon}$. Why this choice works? Thanks in advance.